# avg of multiple columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift

I would like to find the avg of multiple columns instead of rows.
At present, I transposed the table but that's impacting the performance  as my table is very big and by transposing 30 columns the number of rows increased * 29 times.

colum1  measure1 measure2 measure3 avg
abc       100      200      300     200
def       50        60       70     60

I am not going to use all the 30 columns at a time for average and it depends on my parameters in the front end.

I would like to know if there any other solutions to achieve the desired result other than transpose.
In Redshift, I am doing a union of table 29 times to transpose columns to rows.

Your advises would be highly appreciated.

Thanks,
mc

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this (Oracle query):

```
WITH input_data AS (
  SELECT 100 AS measure1, 200 AS measure2 FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 1000 AS measure1, 2000 AS measure2 FROM DUAL
)
SELECT (a.measure1 + a.measure2) / 2 AS measure_avg FROM input_data a
```

Output:

```
MEASURE_AVG
150
1500
```

Comment: Postgres havent system table DUAL

Comment: @Abihabi87 the SELECT statement is the part that matters.

Comment: but in postgres you can use only 'SELECT 100 AS measure1, 200 AS measure2' without 'FROM DUAL'. Default table DUAL not exists in postgres.

Comment: The WITH clause is unimportant is what I meant, sorry, the important part is where I calculate the average which is in the final SELECT query.

Comment: Thank you for all your replies but what if the number of columns that user select is dynamic. I have built a report using Cognos and the user has a prompt with these measures to select.

Comment: @mrcool4 never used Cognos, if it uses SQL I imagine you can add columns in a similar way and divide by number of columns added together.